# Something like the "old" visual basic for web development

Tags: web-applications, language-agnostic

Do you remember the old "good" times when, to make an app, you basically used only one language? Well, that wasn't completely true, because you always has to squeeze some sql here and there, but basically 90% of the time your app was only one language. No matter if was Visual Basic, Delphi, PowerBuilder, or C++, what I like of desktop applications is precisely that: in my opinion, one bad abstractions is better that 5 good ones.
Well, you could agree or not, but the truth is that, to make a web app, you need sql, php (or c#, or java, or ruby, or what ever other language), and javascript, and HTML and CSS. 
I will like to know if exists something that abstracts all of this languages and let create web app as desktop apps.
Do you know any technology like that? more points if is open source and stable.

Comment: Well the tone init is really judgemental and half of it is opinion (i.e. "one bad abstractions is better that 5 good ones"... and that's probably "wrong" anyway) so probably why people tried to close it... but I think it's a valid question although gratingly asked.

Comment: " and that's probably "wrong" anyway".Why? One abstraction let you concentrate in one way of do things, so you could concentrate on solving the problem, not in the tools, instead of switch to 5 different way of thinking. For example, everything is an object is better that this is an object, but that is a function, and that is a query, and that is a table, and that is a procedure, etc

Comment: One way does not mean "good way". It's much easier to just carry a hammer and treat everything as a nail. Monolithic stacks also evolve too slowly and the whole application will suffer. Also, there are many parts to modern web-apps and its good to have the felixiblity of the best tool for each job. Afterall, why not just use flat-files and half-reimplement a database for each project? Really, there is a reason the industry shifted away from what you are describing and in general consider it an anti-pattern. Plus, those are skills most of us should have anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are asking for can be built using libraries from the Clojure ecosystem. Basic building blocks would include

- [A wrapper around HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950056/noir-vs-compojure),
- [A library taking care of interactions with a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294802/use-a-database-with-clojure),
- [An HTML generator or a templating engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474926/clojure-web-framework-for-designers-front-end-devs),
- [A DSL abstracting away the nightmare of CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272262/clojure-dsl-for-css), and
- [ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript), which compiles Clojure to JavaScript.

As a result all languages listed in your question would be hidden behind abstractions written in Clojure, including both the back- and front-end of the application.

I cannot point you to any complete web application stack which fully solves the problem you're describing. The reason is the fact that in the Clojure ecosystem it is conventional to build and publish small libraries which focus on a single problem. As a result you're free to choose the subset of tools which is most appropriate for your use case. You don't get [the gorilla and the jungle](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/19/you-wanted-banana/).

Comment: Might want to look at my answer as Clojure is rather niche.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit) maybe what you are looking for. You write Java code with the JavaScript generated for you. It is also much [more broadly supported than Clojure](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=gwt&word2=clojure).